DeepFace Module Not Found Error on macOS After Installation
I'm developing a web application using CodeIgniter that includes a facial recognition feature for attendance using the DeepFace library. I'm coding on Windows, but when I run my project on macOS, I encounter a "module deepface not found" error.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:
Installed DeepFace using pip install deepface.
Verified my Python version is 3.12.2 and pip version is 24.0.
Installed Flask and confirmed it's working.
Running my script with python api.py still results in the "module deepface not found" error.
For context, I'm using Anaconda as my Python environment. Everything works fine on my Windows setup, but I can't seem to get it to run on macOS.
Any ideas on what might be causing this issue or how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance!

Run python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)" which will print the path of the python executable used when you run python. Make sure that it matches the conda environment and that conda list lists deepfake as installed in the same conda env

Can you try homebrew?
